# MacBook Pro disk failure

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, snow-leopard, hard-drive

Just a few months ago, I bought the latest 2011 MacBook Pro. Now, a few months later, I have a problem. It seems like my notebook is rejecting my hard drive (which is an SSD).

How it all began: yesterday, business as usual, I wanted to log in. After typiing my password and pressing enter, something strange happened. OS X was loading, and loading, and loading, till finally it froze (or gave an error, don't know for sure). But anyway, I couldn't get in, so I restarted my laptop. But it didn't start, it just hung with a no-entry directory. At home, I started to search on the Internet. I repaired my disk, several times. When I inserted another hard drive in my laptop, it worked. When I put my SSD in another MacBook, it works. When I plug my SSD externally to my MacBook, it works. But when I put my SDD inside in my MacBook, it doesn't work.

Has anyone had experience with this problem and know how to solve this without a reinstall?

Comment: The other Hard Drive you plug in the MacBook is a SSD too? What are the specifications of the failing SSD? Is this the first time it does something *weird* ?

Comment: When I say HD, it is not a SSD. SSD is a Vertex 3. This is the first time.

Comment: I have tried everything, also reinstall. Still nothing. I think the problem lays with SATA 3. The SSD works in other computers.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was thinking of.